# How to run a calculation in a sheet using button in excel

Tags: excel, vba, button, command, activex

I am trying to create an form control or activex command button to change a series of values to a particular calculation.

My button is on a sheet named "Sheet 2" and the calculation needs to happen on a sheet named "Whatif back".

When i press the button, C2 in "Whatif back" must be calculated with C27 in "Sheet 2".

My code is:

```
Sub Sheet2_Button18_Click()
Sheets("Whatif back").Range("C2")=(10000+Sheets("Sheet2").Range(C27))
End Sub
```

I am getting a compile error. Please help.

Thank you,
Shyam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with an `ActiveX` button named after "Sheet2_Button18" in worksheet "Sheet2" you use this:

```
Sub Sheet2_Button18_Click()
    Sheets("Whatif back").Range("C2") = 10000 + Range("C27")
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh i see what i did wrong over there. That fixed it! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Nice to know what compile error you're getting, but try:
Range("C27") instead of Range(C27)

(this should be a comment but I don't have rep yet)